# Excel three columns align data

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

I have three columns of data as below

[image]

I'd like to get all Column3 data match to Column1. For example, Data1 should have Value1, Data2 should be empty, Data3 to Value3 and so on ...

Since there maybe some cells in ColumnA that would have no corresponding value in Column3, I'd like fill those with "None" or even leave it blank. I have 700+ fields in Column1 and trying to look for a faster way than filling it manually.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try Vlookup or Xlookup?

Comment: @ScottCraner No, I'm not very familiar with it. Can you give me a base to start off on?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1  It even has a nice video that you can watch.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, did the trick! Good to learn something new